# Webview on a part of the application

Tags: android, webview

Within my application I would like to show a web page within a view in the application.

I am not sure how to apply the view on just a part of the application and open a web page within the view.

The web page within the view will open when the user clicks a button.

The webview will be on the right hand side of the screen like in the image below:

[image]

Is this possible?

Please help. Thanks

Edit:

I have included a tablelayout within the relative layout I already had.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip" android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="#000000" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_marginLeft="250px"
         android:layout_marginTop="80px">
<TableRow>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I then call the webview in my  application like this within an onclick button:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

But nothing happens when I click this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Make one of the cells your web view.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried this but this does not respond. I have edited above. thanks